# Error 401 calling static Html hosted on Cloud Storage from Cloud Endpoint

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-run, terraform-provider-gcp

I am receiving a 401 error when calling a static HTML page hosted on Cloud Storage bucket.

The Cloud Storage bucket is configured as Public.

The call is done from my Cloud Endpoint, as shown below:

```
/my-web-page:
      get:
        summary: call my web page
        operationId: my-web-page
        x-google-allow: all
        x-google-backend:
          address: https://storage.googleapis.com/MY-PROJECT/[MY-BUCKET]/[MY-OBJECT]
        responses:
          '200':
            description: A successful response
            schema:
              type: string
```

Cloud Run Log:

```
XX.XXX.XXX.XXX - "GET https://[MY-CLOUD-ENDPOINT-SERVICE].a.run.app/my-web-page" **401** 804 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.17763"
Expand all | Collapse all{
 httpRequest: {
  latency: "2.377394394s"   
  protocol: "HTTP/1.1"   
  remoteIp: "XXXXX"   
  requestMethod: "GET"   
  requestSize: "693"   
  requestUrl: "https://[MY-CLOUD-ENDPOINT-SERVICE].a.run.app/storage"   
  responseSize: "804"   
  serverIp: "XXXXXXX"   
  status: 401   
  userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.17763"   
 }
 insertId: "5ddef2f900077a8473972018"  
 labels: {…}  
 logName: "projects/[MY-GCP-PROJECT]/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Frequests"  
 receiveTimestamp: "2019-11-27T22:04:41.498296805Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {
   configuration_name: "XXXXX"    
   location: "us-central1"    
   project_id: "XXXXX"    
   revision_name: "XXXX"    
   service_name: "XXXX"    
  }
  type: "cloud_run_revision"   
 }
 severity: "WARNING"  
 timestamp: "2019-11-27T22:04:41.490116Z"  
 trace: "projects/XXXXXX/traces/aed367cb2b64bf00c215f8b19dff446b"  
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you deploy ESP in Cloud Run with flag --allow-unauthenticated ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening here is that the [x-google-backend](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/openapi-extensions#x-google-backend) is attempting to authenticate to Storage by creating a service account identity token.

On the other hand, Storage accepts only OAuth or no authorization at all. The token it gets from ESP is simply ignored and treated as garbage.

You can even use `curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer garbage' https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket/buildings.jpg` and still get the exact same error.

For the time being, there is no way of turning off the authorization in this feature, so it won't be working with googleapis.

An alternative would be modifying the ESP image so that it adds a custom location to nginx config by adding file `/var/lib/nginx/extra/hello.conf` and modifying `gcloud_build_image` to include this config.

This way it will skip the endpoints altogether, so it can be removed from openapi-run.yaml. You can check both files [here](https://github.com/waelmas/esp_to_sotrage).

Let me know if this solves your issue.

Comment: Hi @Waelmas, when I tried to deploy the solution to a new GCP project, I am getting this error:

Comment: INFO - nginx: [warn] the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /home/nginx/endpoints/nginx.conf:29</br>
INFO - 2019/12/10 16:44:13 [warn] 1#1: the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /home/nginx/endpoints/nginx.conf:29</br>
INFO - nginx: [emerg] invalid URL prefix in /var/lib/nginx/extra/hello.conf:8</br>
INFO - 2019/12/10 16:44:13 [emerg] 1#1: invalid URL prefix in /var/lib/nginx/extra/hello.conf:8</br>
ERROR - Container called exit(1).</br>

Comment: It seems the container is not starting because of this nginx config issue

Comment: sorry, forget it about... I had introduced an type on my hello.conf that is causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

As you are doing a request to the Cloud Storage API with the usage of endpoints, I believe that you should use the following address instead:

`https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/[PATH_TO_RESOURCE]`

As the endpoint is most probably doing a JSON request to the API, this [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-endpoints#typical) from the documentation will be useful for you.

**EDIT:**

I finally managed to make it work with your same settings using the following endpoints configuration:

```
/hello:
  get:
    summary: hello
    operationId: GetImage
    x-google-backend:
      #address: https://storage.googleapis.com/[MY-BUCKET]/[MY-OBJECT]
      address: https://storage.cloud.google.com/[MY-BUCKET]/[MY-OBJECT]
    responses:
      '200':
        description: hello
        schema:
          type: object
```

The thing with this setting is that the file will be served from the `storage.cloud.google.com` instead and therefore the user will be redirected to `apidata.googleusercontent.com` instead. I believe that it's not working with the googleapis.com because Endpoints it's not meant to call other APIs, then calling the `storage.google.com` URL will work instead.

Comment: Even in this case, I am receiving:

`code`
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Invalid Credentials",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Invalid Credentials",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "authError",
        "locationType": "header",
        "location": "Authorization"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Then now I will recommend to try narrowing down the issue to see where it is exactly being generated, as you are using GCS, GCRun and Endpoints. I've been trying to reproduce it on my side with no luck so far. However, starting with a public GCS bucket, the following will return an error:
`curl https://storage.googleapis.com/[MY-PROJECT]/[MY-BUCKET]/[OBJECT]`
However, without the project, it is working for me:
`curl https://storage.googleapis.com/[MY-BUCKET]/[OBJECT]`
Could you try that as well? in this case we may disregard that the issue is coming from GCS.

Comment: @FELIPECEMBRANELLI I have updated my answer with a solution that worked out for me, let me know if that works our for you as well.

Comment: Thanks for your return. But it is still not working...The problem is when I tried to access it from a web browser session not authenticated in Google. Have you tested it ? The Google authentication page pops up for me.

Comment: just to complement, the request is redirect to --> https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin/webreauth?service=cds&passive=1209600&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fstorage.cloud.google.com%2F[MY-BUCKET]%2F[MY-OBJECT]&followup=https%3A%2F%2Fstorage.cloud.google.com%2F[MY-BUCKET]%2F[MY-OBJECT]&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in ESP, it always send ID token to the backend.  Since your GCS bucket is public, the request to the storage API should work if it doesn't have any JWT token. But if it has any JWT token, the call fail.

We are working on a fix.  But due to holiday release frozen,  the fix will be available next year.

There is a hack to work around it.

1) deploy your OpenAPi spec by:

```
gcloud endpoints deploy you_open_api.json
```

2) download its compiled config file from Google service management service

```
gcloud endpoints configs describe ... > tmp.xml
```

3) remove the lines with "jwt_audience" in the "Backend" section in the tmp.xml
The idea is: if jwt_audience field is empty, ESP will not generate ID token. But in the x-google-backend OpenApi spec, even you did not specify jwt_audience, the compiler will automatically assign "address" field to the "jwt_audience" field.

4) redeploy the tmp.xml to google service managment by:

```
gcloud endpoints deploy tmp.xml
```

With this change, ESP will not generate ID token when calling storage API.